# ionic $http.post fails in emulator but works in browser and iPhone

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The code below works in browser and on iPhone 5s but not in the iOS emulator. I'm trying to figure out if it's the emulator or something in ionic.

I have set the NSAppTransportSecurity in the Info.plist to be able to use http

NSAppTransportSecurity

    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
    

and the code:

```
accountRepo.register($scope.login.registryCode)
.success(function(data){
    accountRepo.user = data;
    $scope.hideLoading();
    $state.go("setPin");
})
.error(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    $scope.hideLoading();
    alert("Incorrect registry code");
});
```

and the repo

```
app.factory('accountRepo', function($http) {
   return {
     token: {},
     register: function(registryCode) {
       return $http.post("http://localhost:9501/register",
       {"registryCode": registryCode} );
     },
```

The err parameter is null when the error occurs. I get nothing in the output in Xcode. Should I look somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but someone might find this useful.

It's an issue of cross origin resource sharing (CORS), when doing `ionic serve` or `ionic run -l`.

You can solve that by setting a proxy in your `ionic.project`.

Check this article for more: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/